# search for a text uppercase lowercase and letters and signs in all the sheets of my google sheets, in a web app

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I implement this function in the front of my web application, which by entering an input and a button executes the function with the obtained data.

The function does the search in all the sheets of my google sheets, but I want it to show the results in a div or a table.

```
Search input:
```

[![Search in input and display all row][1]][1]

```js
gs

function searchIt(){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const findString = ('Text');
  const textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(findString);
  Logger.log(textFinder);
  const items = textFinder.findAll();
  Logger.log(items);
  //const cell = textFinder.findNext();
  items.forEach(cell=>{
    const row = cell.getRow();
    const col = cell.getColumn();
    Logger.log(`Found at Row:${row} Col:${col}`);
  })
   
  
}
```

Comment: The English translation is OK, but there is also:  [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: The same question in spanish with code include https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/579194/como-puedo-hacer-una-b%c3%basqueda-general-de-toda-mi-hoja-de-google-sheets-y-mostrar

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

gs:

```
function mySearch(s) {
  const token = '';
  const vA = [];
  let oA = [];
  do {
    let resp = Drive.Files.list({ pageToken: token, q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'" });
    token = resp.nextPageToken;
    for (let i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
      let item = resp.items[i];
      vA.push(item.id);
    }
  } while (token)
  vA.forEach(id => {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    let filename = ss.getName();
    let shts = ss.getSheets();
    shts.forEach(sh => {
      let sheetname = sh.getName();
      let tf = sh.createTextFinder(s).findAll();
      tf.forEach(item => {
        oA.push([filename,sheetname,item.row,item.getColumn()])
      })
    })
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oA));
}
```

javascript:

```
function search() {
  let s = document.getElementById("search").value;
  google.script.run.mySearch(s);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it to me, or how can I apply it in my script? Pls, How can I call it on the front with an input

Comment: You are supposed to already know at least some Javascript..  But I added a small Javascript function for you.

Comment: i really appreciate your help cooper, let me tested